# Étale homotopy type of (derived) loop space

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, derived-algebraic-geometry

A feature of derived algebraic geometry is that we have internal homs. Furthermore, we can think of $B\mathbb{Z}$ as the derived algebraic geometric analogue of $S^1$. Thus we have an analogue of the loop space, the derived loop space
$$LX:=\mathbb{R}\operatorname{Map}(B\mathbb{Z},X)$$
using the notation of "Chern character, loop spaces and derived algebraic geometry" (https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00772859/document). My question is how does this interact with the étale homotopy type? Specifically I would like to know if the following is true
$$\operatorname{Et}(LX)=\Omega \operatorname{Et}(X)$$
where the right hand side denotes the loop space of the étale type of $X$. A naive hope for a proof would be
$$\operatorname{Et}(\mathbb{R}\operatorname{Map}(B\mathbb{Z},X))\cong \operatorname{Map}(\operatorname{Et}(B\mathbb{Z}),\operatorname{Et}(X)) \cong \operatorname{Map}(S^1,Et(X))$$
but I don't know if this makes sense.

Comment: The proof should be a bit simpler than that, as you can write $LX = X \times^h_{X \times X} X$. (You can always express maps from a simplicial set as a homotopy limit.) The etale homotopy type won't see any of the derived structure, though.

Comment: @JonPridham So you think this is true? If you add it in an answer, I'm happy to accept it.

Comment: By @Jon Pridham's comment you can see that the etale homotopy type of $LX$ is  $Et(X)$, when $X$ is a scheme. This disagrees with the free loop space of $Et(X)$.

Comment: Could we at least hope that there exists some (derived) scheme $Y$ such that $\Omega Et(X)\cong Et(Y)$?

Comment: It seems unlikely you'd have a natural way of constructing $Y$. Reverting to the original question, Friedlander found a class of smooth morphisms which become fibrations in etale homotopy (after fairly mild completion), so it would be enough to take $X$ to be a higher stack whose diagonal takes lies in that class. In practice, that would mean $BG$ and its higher analogues, for $G$ smooth (no derived structure).

Comment: You could try to cheat and construct a scheme $Y(Z)$ with the homotopy type of an arbitrary simplicial set $Z$, by gluing algebraic simplices together.  I'm not sure if this works /what finiteness conditions you need to impose on $Z$ to get a scheme versus an Ind scheme.

Comment: @PhilTosteson I don't know the "cheat" you are refering to, even though it sounds interesting. Given an arbitrary simplicial set, how do you construct an Ind scheme with that homotopy type?

Comment: Geometry and homotopy theory are different. Etale homotopy type is a functor from geometry to homotopy theory. Stacks and derived schemes are a vertical dimension of homotopy theory along a horizontal geometric space. The derived loop space is a purely homotopical operation acting on the vertical dimension. The etale homotopy type combines the horizontal and vertical data, but that is destructive. In other words, the derived loop space is about small loops in the vertical direction, not large horizontal/geometric loops. Whereas, the etale homotopy type knows about geometric loops.